# Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\AppFolder\FApp\.flutter-plugins". The flutter tool cannot access the file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

**I got this error when I was trying to build the Flutter Project.**

I tried both flutter commands from the terminal and from android studio.

`Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\AppFolder\Flutter-App-v2.0\.flutter-plugins". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.`

`Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.`

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I had restricted access to the folder from the Windows Security Settings.

I had the folder under `Restricted Access` under my Ransomware Protection Files.

To check go to `Windows Security`-> `Virus & Threat Protection` -> `Ransomware protection` -> `Protected Folder`. And remove the files.

If this doesn't solve your problem, try to make a flutter project in any other folder. Or there is something that is not allowing the Flutter SDK to make changes on that folder. It can be your `antivirus software` too.